# Is there any reason for those network sign-ins?

Tags: wifi, login

What I mean by that is, when you connect to a public place's WiFi hotspot, you can log in without a password, but then you have to go to the browser and click a button to log in. Is there any reason for that, or is it just so the manager can thank you for being in his place and wish you an enjoyable experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are typically accepting a terms of use agreement when you log in or click OK.  So in general it's mostly for legal purposes.